# Keras VGG16 same model different approach gave different result

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i build keras CNN based on VGG16 model to classify flower and the dataset is [here](https://www.kaggle.com/alxmamaev/flowers-recognition/). I build two models with the same architecture and sum of parameters but difference approach. One using [Model](https://keras.io/models/model/) (functional API) and the other using [Sequential](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/). Sequential gave me good result (84% val_acc) but Model gave me poor results (50% val_acc). I hope some one can point out whats the difference. Thanks!

**Sequential**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import numpy as np
import time

## image path
train_data_dir = 'dataset/training_set'
validation_data_dir = 'dataset/test_set'
## other
img_width, img_height = 299, 299
nb_train_samples = 100
nb_validation_samples = 800
top_epochs = 50
fit_epochs = 50
batch_size = 24
nb_classes = 5
nb_epoch = 10

#　start measurement
start = time.time()

# import vgg16 model
input_tensor = Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
vgg16 = keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)

# creating an FC layer
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=vgg16.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))
top_model.summary()
# bound VGG 16 and FC layer
vgg_model = Model(inputs=vgg16.input, outputs=top_model(vgg16.output))

print(vgg_model.layers[:15])
# prevent re-learning of the layer before the last convolution layer
for layer in vgg_model.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False
vgg_model.summary()
# create model
vgg_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Setting learning data
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True
)

history = vgg_model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
        epochs=nb_epoch,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples
)
```

**Sequential-network**

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)        (None, 299, 299, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 299, 299, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 299, 299, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 149, 149, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 149, 149, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 149, 149, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 74, 74, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 74, 74, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 74, 74, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 74, 74, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 37, 37, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 37, 37, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 37, 37, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 37, 37, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 18, 18, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 9, 9, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_6 (Sequential)    (None, 5)                 10618373  
=================================================================
Total params: 25,333,061
Trainable params: 17,697,797
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
```

**Sequential - result**

```
Epoch 1/10
100/100 [==============================] - 50s 498ms/step - loss: 1.2821 - acc: 0.4912 - val_loss: 0.7209 - val_acc: 0.7327
Epoch 2/10
100/100 [==============================] - 48s 477ms/step - loss: 0.5827 - acc: 0.7787 - val_loss: 0.5326 - val_acc: 0.7816
Epoch 3/10
100/100 [==============================] - 47s 466ms/step - loss: 0.5355 - acc: 0.8101 - val_loss: 0.4951 - val_acc: 0.8150
Epoch 4/10
100/100 [==============================] - 46s 458ms/step - loss: 0.4020 - acc: 0.8612 - val_loss: 0.4458 - val_acc: 0.8413
Epoch 5/10
100/100 [==============================] - 49s 485ms/step - loss: 0.3465 - acc: 0.8767 - val_loss: 0.3904 - val_acc: 0.8496
Epoch 6/10
100/100 [==============================] - 46s 460ms/step - loss: 0.3330 - acc: 0.8747 - val_loss: 0.3961 - val_acc: 0.8568
Epoch 7/10
100/100 [==============================] - 45s 448ms/step - loss: 0.3188 - acc: 0.8896 - val_loss: 0.4462 - val_acc: 0.8389
Epoch 8/10
100/100 [==============================] - 47s 472ms/step - loss: 0.2302 - acc: 0.9208 - val_loss: 0.4048 - val_acc: 0.8568
Epoch 9/10
100/100 [==============================] - 45s 453ms/step - loss: 0.2172 - acc: 0.9192 - val_loss: 0.4101 - val_acc: 0.8795
Epoch 10/10
100/100 [==============================] - 45s 453ms/step - loss: 0.1867 - acc: 0.9321 - val_loss: 0.3337 - val_acc: 0.8878
```

**Model**

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras import optimizers
train_data_dir = 'dataset/training_set'
validation_data_dir = 'dataset/test_set'
## other
img_width, img_height = 299, 299
nb_train_samples = 100
nb_validation_samples = 800
top_epochs = 50
fit_epochs = 50
batch_size = 24
nb_classes = 5
nb_epoch = 10

#build CNN

model_vgg16_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

input = Input(shape=(299,299, 3),name = 'image_input')

output_vgg16_conv = model_vgg16_conv(input)

for layer in model_vgg16_conv.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False
model_vgg16_conv.summary()

x = Flatten(name='flatten')(output_vgg16_conv)
x = Dense(256, activation='softmax')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

vgg_model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)

vgg_model.summary()


#Image preprocessing and image augmentation with keras
vgg_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Setting learning data
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True
)

history = vgg_model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
        epochs=nb_epoch,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples
)
```

**Model-network**

```
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    image_input (InputLayer)     (None, 299, 299, 3)       0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    vgg16 (Model)                multiple                  14714688  
    _________________________________________________________________
    flatten (Flatten)            (None, 41472)             0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 256)               10617088  
    _________________________________________________________________
    dropout_10 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    predictions (Dense)          (None, 5)                 1285      
    =================================================================
    Total params: 25,333,061
    Trainable params: 17,697,797
    Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
```

**Model-result**

```
Epoch 1/10
100/100 [==============================] - 48s 484ms/step - loss: 1.6028 - acc: 0.2379 - val_loss: 1.5978 - val_acc: 0.1814
Epoch 2/10
100/100 [==============================] - 47s 470ms/step - loss: 1.5758 - acc: 0.3098 - val_loss: 1.5577 - val_acc: 0.3258
Epoch 3/10
100/100 [==============================] - 45s 455ms/step - loss: 1.5352 - acc: 0.3386 - val_loss: 1.5273 - val_acc: 0.3496
Epoch 4/10
100/100 [==============================] - 45s 453ms/step - loss: 1.4991 - acc: 0.3425 - val_loss: 1.4890 - val_acc: 0.3914
Epoch 5/10
100/100 [==============================] - 47s 472ms/step - loss: 1.4600 - acc: 0.3826 - val_loss: 1.4406 - val_acc: 0.4523
Epoch 6/10
100/100 [==============================] - 46s 456ms/step - loss: 1.4252 - acc: 0.4021 - val_loss: 1.4337 - val_acc: 0.4165
Epoch 7/10
100/100 [==============================] - 45s 453ms/step - loss: 1.3944 - acc: 0.4037 - val_loss: 1.3720 - val_acc: 0.4964
Epoch 8/10
100/100 [==============================] - 48s 479ms/step - loss: 1.3787 - acc: 0.4193 - val_loss: 1.3615 - val_acc: 0.4988
Epoch 9/10
100/100 [==============================] - 46s 464ms/step - loss: 1.3590 - acc: 0.4067 - val_loss: 1.3272 - val_acc: 0.4952
Epoch 10/10
100/100 [==============================] - 45s 449ms/step - loss: 1.3419 - acc: 0.4244 - val_loss: 1.3038 - val_acc: 0.5060
```

Comment: Just a typo: you have used `activation='softmax'` for the second last Dense layer in the second model.

Comment: for the second last Dense layer change it to `activation="relu"`. Also does this problem still occur if you change from SGD to "rmsprop"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `softmax` unit in Dense is an ensemble of `sigmoid` functions. The way it works is similar to a `multi class classifier` that works by having `one classifier per class`. Sigmoid is very good for identifying binary outputs like 1 or 0. Therefore a softmax will be very good for the output layer but not so good as an intermediate layer.

The in-depth explaination would be that backpropagation over a `relu` unit preserves the intermediate features while `softmax` doesn't do as good a job for that but does much better at the output layer.

Here is the difference

> top_model = Sequential()
>
> top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=vgg16.output_shape[1:]))
>
> top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='**relu**'))
>
> top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
>
> top_model.add(Dense(nb_classes,activation='softmax'))
>
> top_model.summary()

Whereas

> x = Flatten(name='flatten')(output_vgg16_conv)
>
> x = Dense(256, activation='**softmax**')(x)
>
> x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
>
> x = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

Good to see that you are retraining imagenet by transfer learning! :)

Let us know if that fixed the problem or leave a comment if something else is also needed!

Comment: Wow silly me, i miss that out. The code sometimes overwhelming for beginner like me. I looking the answer for hours and turn out it just silly problem. It works fine right now. Thanks dev!